# Mapbox iOS sdk: How to update shape layers at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, mapbox

I recently started using the Mapbox SDK for iOS in one of our new apps, as we needed a replacement for native MapKit of Google Maps SDK, because we need to display around 65.000 points on a map, and this makes the native map solutions very slow and causes memory problems on older devices. Although the Mapbox SDK is working just fine, I find it difficult to find relevant information for the following problem:

Is it possible to update a (in our case) 'MGLCircleStyleLayer' with new GeoJson data every x seconds, and this without having to remove and re-add the whole source/layer. This last option works, but between removing the existing layer, and adding the layer again, the circles disappear for a second, and than re-appear. We tried adding a new layer, and later remove the old one so the circles stay visible, but this causes:

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

after just a few updates.

This is the code I currently use to add the layer. The displayed data is scattered over the whole global map:

```
    MGLShapeSource *dataSource = [[MGLShapeSource alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"data-source" URL:serverDataURL options:nil];
    [mainMapView.style addSource:dataSource];

    MGLCircleStyleLayer *dataLayer = [[MGLCircleStyleLayer alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"data-layer" source:dataSource];

    NSDictionary *colors = @{@1: [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:[UIColor whiteColor]],
                             @2: [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:[UIColor yellowColor]],
                             @3: [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:[UIColor orangeColor]],
                             @4: [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.987 green:0.237 blue:0.032 alpha:1]],
                             @5: [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.985 green:0 blue:0.027 alpha:1]],
                             @6: [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.686 green:0 blue:0.014 alpha:1]]
                             };
    dataLayer.circleOpacity = [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:@0.7];
    dataLayer.circleColor = [MGLStyleValue valueWithInterpolationMode: MGLInterpolationModeInterval
                                                          sourceStops: colors
                                                        attributeName: @"colorcode"
                                                              options: nil];

    dataLayer.circleRadius = [MGLStyleValue valueWithInterpolationMode:MGLInterpolationModeExponential
                                                       cameraStops:@{
                                                                     @12: [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:@2],
                                                                     @22: [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:@180]
                                                                     }
                                                           options: @{MGLStyleFunctionOptionDefaultValue:@1.75}];

    [mainMapView.style addLayer:dataLayer];
```

This part is working just fine as it is. Only, when I try to **update** this, I run into problems like (for example):

> identifier data-source already exists

Adding new layers with a new identifier, as already explained, works fine but leaves a gap between removing and re-adding the layer for about a second (even when most of the work in done outside the main thread).

I don't find any good examples on the Mapbox website, and there is not much info on Google to go on.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't, I could only solve this by deleting the layers and re-initialize them...

Comment: @HoeZo-IT could you show how are you deleting them? When I do that Mapbox crashes...